# Conditional Formatting in Rdlc

Tags: rdlc

I want to set the color of column values in my rdlc table based on its value.Heres what I have done.        `=IIF(Fields!gpa.Value="Good",Fields!gpa.Color.Format("Red"),Fields!gpa.Color.Format("Blue"))`  
It only prints Red or Blue instead of actual value and Color of font remains same.What Am I doing wrong here and how can I fix it?.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set "Color" property of the cell using just color name or hex code:

`=IIF(Fields!gpa.Value="Good","Red","Blue")`

`=IIF(Fields!gpa.Value="Good","#AF1E2D","#3232CC")`

(codes used are just examples)

Comment: Works great. Thank you